# iTunes Connect, TestFlight and Jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins, app-store-connect, testflight

I am trying to understand how I can implement my current workflow using Apples TestFlight integration into iTunes Connect.

**At present I have a Jenkins continuous integration server that compiles and uploads a new build to TestFlight every time someone pushes into github.**

From what I can see, there is no official command line API for iTunes Connect for uploading new builds.

I can't afford to manually compile and upload 10 apps every time I make a code change.

How can I implement this workflow with the existing tools and iTunes Connect? (Jenkins, Bots, xcodebuild, application loader, etc...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using [Shenzhen](https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen) with itunesconnect option:

```
$ ipa distribute:itunesconnect -a me@email.com -p myitunesconnectpassword --upload
```

In case of Jenkins it would be "Execute Shell" type of Build step.

Comment: Cool, a new feature of Shenzhen. Shenzhen is not working properly right now with xcode 6 but under the hood it is using iTMSTransporter.

Comment: @Elvin R. Thanks. Except --upload it was not sent to Beta Users under testFlight. But --upload solve my query. Cheers.....

Answer (score 10):

or you can use altool : */Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool*

**Usage:**

```
altool --validate-app -f file -u username [-p password]
altool --upload-app -f file -u username [-p password]
```

Comment: For this command to execute, I would need Xcode installed on the machine running jenkins right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [deliver testflight](https://github.com/krausefx/deliver#testflight) for a very easy upload of your `ipa` file to Apple TestFlight. The advantage of `deliver` over `shenzhen` is that `deliver` will actually enable the new build for testers to install.

Comment: I could not find in **deliver** an option to automate the *build number* increment. Is it possible at all?

Comment: @AlexCohn Sure thing, you can use the built-in fastlane action for that https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/docs/Actions.md#increment_build_number

Comment: Is there any good tutorial that you can point to which provides Xcode -> tesflight integration via jenkins for this tool?